# Typescript Path aliases outside rootDir in tsconfig

Tags: typescript

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62951204/500902) question, but it is slightly different and has no answers

I have a couple of git submodules.  They are large existing projects, and I thought I could just reuse pieces directly like:

```
myproject/
   src/
   submod1/src
   submod2/src
```

with tsconfig.json like

```
        <snip...>
        "rootDir": "src/",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "paths": {
            "@submod1/*": [ "submod1/src/*" ],
            "@submod1/*": [ "submod2/src/*" ],
            "@app/*": [ "src/*" ]
        },
```

And in my code things like

```
import { SomeVar } from '@submod1/constants';
```

But vscode (and tsc presumably) are reporting
`File '<path>/submod1/src/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '<path>/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

I'm just trying to do something simple and pragmatic.  Is there a way to achieve this?  I guess I could do something with symlinks, but that seems like a big mistake.  I could put the submodules under src/ but that also seems wrong.

Comment: I'd remove `rootDir` from `tsconfig.json` to let TSC infer its value. To restrict TSC to source files under `src/` either move `tsconfig.json` from `myproject/` to `src/` or leave it under `myproject/` and add `"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"], ` to it.

Comment: Did you solve this at the end? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not really @JavierGuzmán.  Kind of moved on to other things

Comment: Maybe my anwser solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71521880/tsconfig-problems-with-test-and-compiling/72407164#72407164

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there's no 'clear' solution to this. You can either

- include the whole `myproject` in your `tsconfig.json`'s `rootDir` which might be error prone if you're going to have more modules and wouldn't like to reuse anything besides `submod1` and `submod2`

or

- use the `rootDirs` property to [selectively include all the needed submodules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDirs)

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src", "submod1/src", "submod2/src"]
  }
}
```