# tsconfig problems with test and compiling

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, eslint

This is my *tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.json",
    "tests/**/*.ts"
  ],
}
```

My architecture is as follows:

```
├── tests
├── src
├── eslint.yml
├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
```

The problem with this structure is that in the `dist` folder it looks like this:

```
dist
├── tests
├── src
```

So I could change *rootDir* to `src`, problem that the `tests` folder cannot be outside of `src`.

What I want is to be able to use typescript in both the `tests` folder and the `src` folder. What would be the solution in that case. I've searched in several places and haven't found a solution to my problem.

Maybe some changes might affect `eslint`, because it imports `tsconfig.json`

My *eslintrc.yml*:

```
env:
  es2017: true
  node: true
  jest: true
extends:
  - airbnb-base
  - "eslint:recommended"
  - "plugin:import/typescript"
parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
parserOptions:
  ecmaVersion: 2020
  sourceType: module
  project: "./tsconfig.json"
plugins:
  - "@typescript-eslint"
settings:
  "import/resolver":
    typescript: {}
ignorePatterns:
  - "dist/*"
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there any problem in keeping the corresponding `tsconfig.json` in their own dedicated file. For example, take out test specific configuration in it's own file, say `test.tsconfig.json`?

Comment: You still can have a shared `tsconfig.json` between a `main.tsconfig.json` and `test.tsconfig.json` by using `extends` property inside `tsconfig` options.

Comment: @NalinRanjan How can I do that?

Comment: Check [extends](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) `tsconfig.json` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following *@fast-reflexes* answer and after a lot of research I arrived at the following answer:

1. On `package.json` keep using only tsc command to compile:

> ```
> {
>     ...
>     "scripts": {
>         ...
>         "build": "tsc",
>         ...
>     },
>     ...
> }
> ```

2. My `tsconfig.json` change a little bit.

> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "noImplicitAny": true,
>     "declaration": false,
>     "strict": true,
>     "strictNullChecks": false,
>     "target": "ES2019",
>     "module": "commonjs",
>     "resolveJsonModule": true,
>     "allowJs": true,
>     "checkJs": false,
>     "outDir": "dist",
>     "esModuleInterop": true,
>     "inlineSourceMap": true,
>     "rootDir": "./src",        //  this line changed
>     "baseUrl": "./src",        //  this line changed
>     "typeRoots": [
>       "./node_modules/@types"
>     ],
>     "paths": {
>       "@/*": [
>         "*"                    //  this line changed
>       ]
>     }
>   },
>   "include": [
>     "src/**/*.ts",
>     "src/**/*.js",
>     "src/**/*.json"            //  remove line related to tests
>   ],
> }
> ```

3. Created `tsconfig.eslint.json`.

> ```
> {
>   "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "rootDir": "./",
>     "baseUrl": "./",
>     "paths": {
>       "@/*": [
>         "src/*"
>       ]
>     }
>   },
>   "include": [
>     "src/**/*.ts",
>     "src/**/*.js",
>     "src/**/*.json",
>     "tests/**/*.spec.ts"              //  line related to tests
>   ]
> }
> ```

4. My `eslintrc.yml` changed:

> ```
> env:
>   es2017: true
>   node: true
>   jest: true
> extends:
>   - airbnb-base
>   - "eslint:recommended"
>   - "plugin:import/typescript"
> parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
> parserOptions:
>   ecmaVersion: 2020
>   sourceType: module
>   project:
>     - "./tsconfig.json"
>     - "./tsconfig.eslint.json"      <-- added this file
> plugins:
>   - "@typescript-eslint"
> settings:
>   "import/resolver":
>     typescript: {}
> ignorePatterns:
>   - ".eslintrc.yml"                 <-- added this file
>   - "dist/*"
> ```

5. My architecture is as follows:

> ```
> ├── dist
>     ├── subfolders_without_tests               
> ├── tests
>     ├── tsconfig.json               <-- added this file
> ├── src
> ├── eslintrc.yml
> ├── jest.config.js
> ├── tsconfig.json
> ├── tsconfig.eslint.json            <-- added this file
> ├── package.json
> ```

6. My `jest.config.js`:

> ```
> const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
> const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.json');
>
> module.exports = {
>   preset: 'ts-jest',
>   testEnvironment: 'node',
>   testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts'],
>   moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/src/' }),
>   modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/dist'],
>   coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
>     '<rootDir>/dist',
>   ],
>   coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'text', 'cobertura', 'text-summary'],
>   moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
>   collectCoverage: false,
>   collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{ts,js,jsx}'],
> };
> ```

Other related links:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12463#issuecomment-389733188
- https://medium.com/@gokulc/configuring-module-resolution-on-typescript-and-jest-b17a93ebf54d

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to follow the pattern where tests are put in the same folder as the source files they're testing but with an infix `test`. It will make your life easier in the long run.

Buuut... given your current needs:

### 1. Post-process output folder

The simplest solution is to replace your (presumed) build script, in `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "build": "tsc",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

with the following, updating the output folder as desired

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "build": "tsc && rm -rf ./dist/tests && mv ./dist/src/* ./dist && rmdir ./dist/src",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

### 2. Extend Typescript config

You can also add an extra Typescript config only used by Lint. Set `rootDir` to `./src` and remove the `include` that involves the `tests` folder in `tsconfig.json` and then add the following `tsconfig.eslint.json` Typescript config:

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "./"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.js",
        "src/**/*.json",
        "tests/**/*.ts"
    ],
}
```

Now use this config in your `.eslintrc.yml` only and it should work since it overrides both the `rootDir` and the `include` array.

I would have wished for some other solutions as well but even though you can add a temporary `rootDir` as a command line option to `tsc`, it will complain about includes that are outside of the root dir and there is no smooth way to replace the `include` array on the command line (except for literally lining up all the files to compile which is not an option).

In some project I was really motivated to keep a separate `tests` folder as you do here, but I remember that in the end, I just fell back to the tests-in-sources pattern instead because of the number of ridiculous configuration problems that I got with this other approach.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem and found the following solution.

1. Remove `rootDir`from `tsconfig.json`
2. Use the `includes` property to include `src` and `tests` dir

```json
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2020",
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "allowJs": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      // "rootDir": "./src",
      ...
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.json",
    "tests/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
```

3. Use [swc](https://swc.rs/) as the builder tool

```json
//.swcrc
{
  "env": {
    "targets": {
      "node": 16
    }
  },
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "tsx": false
    }
  },
  "module": {
    "type": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

```json
//package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "swc src -d dist --copy-files"
    ...
  },
  ...
```