# How can I include a typescript folder outside the project root in the build and alias the path

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a folder of typescript code that I want to share between two TS projects in a repo. It's various helper classes and DB models. They don't have unifying logic of their own, so it  doesn't make sense to make them into a library.

If I include the common folder in the `paths` config ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths)), or the `rootDirs` ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDirs)), the root of the output folder changes to the most common path ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDir)). Instead, I want to keep each project folder as output root, and instead build the common folder into that root of each project.

I imagine that if I alias the common folder JS destination using `paths`, I can use it in my imports.

How do I achieve this? ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951204/typescript-paths-aliases-with-folder-outside-my-project-root)).

##### input:

```
/project1/**/*.ts
/project2/**/*.ts
/common/**/*.ts
```

##### output project1:

```
/project1/**/*.js
/project1/common/**/*.js
```

##### output project2:

```
/project2/**/*.js
/project2/common/**/*.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a dependency package, just make a dependency package

If you use `workspaces` feature of yarn/pnpm/whatever, you may make multiple packages at once, which works great with a bunch of dependent packages

If you use `link` feature of yarn/pnpm/whatever, you may link your package as a dependency of another your package locally. See `bundled dependencies` on how to include it into build

Comment: Could you elaborate or show an example of how to do this?

Comment: @Manu https://pnpm.io/workspaces